# Table Sort Implementation using Jquery in PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am attempting to implement the TableSort: http://tablesorter.com, then later I will be implementing the pagination.

However, nothing is appearing to happen after implementation.  I follwed the steps on the tablesorter webpage.

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="/libs/js/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/libs/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/libs/js/jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="/libs/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
       { 
           $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
       } 
    ); 
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
      $page_title = 'All Product';
      require_once('includes/load.php');
      // Checkin What level user has permission to view this page
       page_require_level(2);
      $products = join_product_table();
    ?><?php include_once('layouts/header.php'); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php echo display_msg($msg); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="add_product.php">Add New</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">#</th>
                                <th>Photo</th>
                                <th>Product Title</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Category</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Instock</th><!--<th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Buying Price </th>
                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;"> Saleing Price </th>-->
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%;">Product Added</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 100px;">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($products as $product):?>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo count_id();?></td>
                                <td><?php if($product['media_id'] === '0'): ?><img alt="" class="img-avatar" src="uploads/products/no_image.jpg"> <?php else: ?> <img alt="" class="img-avatar" src="uploads/products/%3C?php%20echo%20$product['image'];%20?%3E"> <?php endif; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo remove_junk($product['name']); ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($product['categorie']); ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo remove_junk($product['quantity']); ?></td><!--<td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($product['buy_price']); ?></td>
                <td class="text-center"> <?php echo remove_junk($product['sale_price']); ?></td>-->
                                <td class="text-center"><?php echo read_date($product['date']); ?></td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" href="edit_product.php?id=%3C?php%20echo%20(int)$product['id'];?%3E" title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" href="delete_product.php?id=%3C?php%20echo%20(int)$product['id'];?%3E" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr><?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><?php include_once('layouts/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Resulting image with test data.
[image: Picture of results]

Edit, browser console:
[image: Browser Console Error]

Comment: Any error in browser console

Comment: @Zachary Hanshaw What error are you getting?

Comment: @Ayush   Sorry, I though I add that, the post has been edited.  I don't understand why it isn't finding the tablesorter function.

Comment: @Anant See above comment. Thanks!

Comment: @ZacharyHanshaw I can see in your scripts tag that you have included 2 same jquery files. Both are same files. It can cause conflicts. Remove one of them. Also, move your script tags to the end of the code after the body tag. Try this out.